# SQL Query: Parameter input=[Buyers.Name], get other [Buyers.Name]s who have the same [Stores.StoreID]

Tags: sql

Input=**[Buyers.Name]**, get other **[Buyers.Name]s** who have the same **[Stores.StoreID]s**.

Example: Input "Sten" (**BuyerID 1**), get "Patrick"(**BuyerID 3**) because both have **StoreID 13**.

**TABLES**

Buyers

| BuyerID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sten |
| 2 | Henry |
| 3 | Patrick |

Stores

| BuyerID | StoreID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | **13** |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | **13** |

As I am a new user, I can't add images to the post.

**[Simplified view of the tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/allkt.png)**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` with a subquery:

```
select distinct s.buyerid
from sellers s
where s.storeid in (select s2.storeid
                    from sellers s2 join
                         buyers b2
                         on s2.buyerId = b2.buyerId
                    where b2.name = 'Sten'
                   );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=271e8fb35fdf68d53749bbe440f2482d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. How do you just make up the "s" and "b" out of nowhere? I understand it's "s" for seller and "b" for buyer, but how is it supposed to know that without ever determining it?

Comment: @Rele . . . I have no idea what your comment is about.  `s`, `s2`, and `b2` are well defined as table aliases in the query.  There is no `b`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really a beginner at this... Thanks for the reply. I tried the code in the exact same way and changing it a lot of ways, still haven't gotten it to work. I'll learn more and try to figure it out. The table names are not in english actually so changing those to the right table names might be the problem. Both tables start with the same letter, that got me confused.

Comment: @Rele . . . The major issue was a bad table name.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Turns out the problem was having "JOIN" not "INNER JOIN", although I read that's the same thing and typing out "INNER" is optional. I get a list of BuyerID's not names though...

Comment: @Rele . . . In the SQL standard and every reputable database, `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are equivalent.

Comment: How could I make it give me BuyerNames not BuyerIDs though? (Output)

Comment: @Rele . . . You would need to add a `JOIN` in the outer query.